sequelize error when filtering nested columns using the '$nested.column$' syntax
I am trying to add anyField filter logic to my generic controller list method for my expressjs app using sequelize for my db logic and I can't figure out how to fix this:
I am passing in the anyFieldOptions (fields that can be searched across) to the controller from my routes
generateAllCrudRoutes( apiAdminRouter, '/company_pilots', controllers.company_pilots, {
  needsPagination: true,
  includeModels: [ {
    model: Pilot,
    as: 'pilot',
    include: [ { model: User, as: 'user', duplicating: false } ]
  } ],
  anyFieldOptions: [
    '$pilot.user.firstName$', // Use correct alias and reference nested columns with $
    'pilot.user.lastName',
    'pilot.user.email',
    'pilot.user.mobile$',
    'pilot.user.passport_number',
    'pilot.user.sa_id_number'
  ],
} )

then in my controller list method I try and apply the filters:
if ( anyField && this.anyFieldOptions.length > 0 ) {
        // Initialize an array to store the dynamic includes for this query
        queryOptions.where[ Op.or ] = this.anyFieldOptions.map( field => {
          const parts = field.split( '.' ) // Split field on dots

          if ( parts.length > 1 ) { 
            return {
              [ `$${ field }$` ]: { [ Op.iLike ]: `%${ anyField }%` } // Use the aliased field for querying
            }
          } else {
            // Simple field (no nested association)
            return {
              [ field ]: { [ Op.iLike ]: `%${ anyField }%` }
            }
      }
   } )
}

but when I search with nested field I get
error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pilot->user"

sql output
sql: `SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "CompanyPilots" AS "CompanyPilot" WHERE ("pilot->user"."firstName" ILIKE '%man%' OR "pilot->user"."lastName" ILIKE '%man%' OR "pilot->user"."email" ILIKE '%man%' OR "pilot->user"."mobile" ILIKE '%man%' OR "pilot->user"."passport_number" ILIKE '%man%' OR "pilot->user"."sa_id_number" ILIKE '%man%');`,

clearly not implementing the joins
but the includes and aliased associations are working for my standard list operation prior to filtering.
filtering anyField at the top level works fine.
Here is a gist of the full list method showing the code where I add the include option

Please show the code where you add include option

Here is a gist of the full list method showing the code where I add the include option
https://gist.github.com/manuweg/4db4047537c29b368e482a563a670bf9

I see in this.model.count( { where: queryOptions.where } ) you don't pass any include options that's why the SQL contains only the main model's table.

That seems to make a big difference but now I am seeing some very strange behaviour where I can use the anyField filter for deeply nested fields on some models but not on others. I think you have answered the question though even if it is strangely not working consistently across all models
